# Simple Python-Turlte Module

Tags: python

Quick Question.
How do I make Python Turtle Graphics screen pop-up directly on my screen and not in the background where I have to manually click on it to open it. I need to watch Python draw

Answer (score 1):

To make your question Quick you need to post some code.

```
import turtle

myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
myTurtle.circle(50)
turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()
```

starts on foreground for me (tried to run from komodo edit and command line on Ubuntu 64)